# how to add a tool to eclipse-cdt to automatically generate a header file during make

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a tool that converts an data file into a C header file for inclusion into my project.
Now I would like to have this tool run automatically during make whenever the data file changes.

Where can I tell Eclipse CDT which tool to run and what data file the header depends on?

Answer (score 2):

The article "[Extending the Eclipse CDT Managed Build System](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/197002115?pgno=1)" can give a concrete example of the managed build system (MBS) of CDT.

The MBS can [be **extended**](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/mbs/extensibilityGuide/Managed_Build_Extensibility.html) by modifying/adding a "tool" to the tool-chain (An ordered set of tools used to transform the project resources into the final output (build artifacts) of the project)

[image: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/cdt_build_system/whats_new/4.0/whats_2.gif]

You should be able to add your tool, and set it up to be active for each file modification.

Answer (score 0):

Open the properties of your project. There is an entry "Builders" where you can add other executables to the build.

Comment: Thanks. However, this ALWAYS executes the builder, not only when the input file changed. How can I tell about the dependencies?

Comment: Not this way, sorry. This is just a simple way to add extra builders. The makefile must contain the rules to handle the dependencies.